# Can we make the set of all non-negative integers a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can we define any kind of addition and multiplication on the set of all non-negative integers such that it becomes a field. I think not. Can we prove this ? If we have only a finite collection with prime cardinality then only it may become a field.

Comment: We can turn a set of any cardinality into a field (and for at most countable sets, this does not even require choice or anything like that).

Comment: Pick any bijection of $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ and transport the field operations to $\mathbb{N}$ via that.

Comment: @Tobias: Any _infinite_ cardinality. Finite sets can only become fields if their size is a prime power.

Comment: ohh, this was trivial.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, thank you. I was a bit fast there :)

Comment: There is an interesting field structure on natural numbers, due to John Conway, I believe; google "nimbers". I might add an answer eventually about this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what you could do: the rational numbers are countable, so you can find a bijection $\phi: \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{Q}$ ($\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$). Now $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, so can define multiplication and addition making $\mathbb{N}_0$ into a field.

You can define, for example, addition $\mathbb{N}_0$ by:
$$
a + b = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a) + \phi(b)) \\
$$

If you for example order $\mathbb{Q} = \{a_0, a_1, \dots \}$ like [this site suggests](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countable):
$$
a_0 =\frac 0 1, a_1 = \frac 1 1, a_2 = \frac {-1} 1, \frac 1 2, \frac {-1} 2, \frac 2 1, \frac {-2} 1, \frac 1 3, \frac 2 3,  \frac {-1} 3,\\ \frac {-2} 3, \frac 3 1, \frac 3 2, \frac {-3} 1, \frac {-3} 2, \frac 1 4, \frac 3 4, \frac {-1} 4, \frac {-3} 4, \frac 4 1, \frac 4 3, \frac {-4} 1, \frac {-4} 3 \ldots
$$
Then in $\mathbb{N}$ you would have
$$
3\cdot 4 = \phi^{-1}(a_3a_4) = \phi^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}) = \phi^{-1}(\frac{-1}{4}) = 17.
$$

Comment: +1 for actually putting in a detailed calculation with an actual bijection.